# django restful-framework display format

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint that gives a response like this

```
 "trailer": [
                {
                    "trailerurl": "http://www.you/1"
                }, 
                {
                    "trailerurl": "http://www.you/2"
                }, 
                {
                    "trailerurl": "http://www.you/3"
                }
            ]
```

I am interested in having a response like this, without the objects wrapping the url

```
  "trailer": [
                 "http://www.you/1", 
                 "http://www.you/2", 
                 "http://www.you/3"
            ]
```

Here are my current serializers

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trailer = MovieTrailerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='trailer_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('trailer',)


class MovieTrailerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    class Meta:
        model = Trailer
        fields = (  'trailerurl', )
```

Comment: What methods have you defined in you're Movie and Trailer classes ?
You may have a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys), especialy the note on natural_keys. Hope this help.

Comment: did you mean views?? I use ````ListAPIView````

Comment: I still not get it . this ?? ````from rest_framework import serializers````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `SerializerMethodField`.

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trailer = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('trailer',)

    def get_trailer(self, obj):
        trailers = []

        for trailer in obj.trailer_set.all():
            trailers.append(trailer.trailerurl)

        return trailers
```

Comment: first one with error ````'module' object has no attribute 'ListField'````